# JavaScript How to convert a string into a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, reduce

I have a response string like this:

```
|||COVID HPI^^^FEVER^^^Low Grade
|||COVID HPI^^^FEVER^^^Continuous
|||COVID HPI^^^RHINORRHEA/SNEEZING^^^No
|||GENERAL EXAM^^^CL^^^Conscious
|||GENERAL EXAM^^^ORIENTED^^^Yes
```

And i want to convert it into something like this:

```
{
  "COVID HPI": [
    {
      "FEVER": "Low Grade, Continuous",
      "RHINORRHEA/SNEEZING": "Yes"
    }
  ],
  "GENERAL EXAM": [
    {
      "CL": "Conscious",
      "ORIENTED": "Yes"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not able to go beyond this without an ugly code:

```
const na = [];
    fetch('http://localhost/test/json/newdata.json')
    .then(response => {
       let vv = response.json();
       return vv;
    })
    .then(function(data){
    console.log(data[0]['tRxVal'])
        let nav = data[0]['tRxVal'].slice(3).split('|||');
        let nbv = nav.map(function(item,i){
            return item.split('^^^');
        });
        //console.log(nbv);
        nbv.forEach(function(v,i){
            if(!na.includes(v[0])){
                na.push(v[0]);
            }
        })
        console.log(na)

    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle errors
    });
```

Can someone please help me with this
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split by `|||` to get each row, and then split each row by `^^^`. Then, you can think of each "row" like this: `<topLevelCategory>^^^<subCategory>^^^<subCategoryAnswer>`. Use this mental model of each row to build your object around.

```js
const string = `|||COVID HPI^^^FEVER^^^Low Grade
|||COVID HPI^^^FEVER^^^Continuous
|||COVID HPI^^^RHINORRHEA/SNEEZING^^^No
|||GENERAL EXAM^^^CL^^^Conscious
|||GENERAL EXAM^^^ORIENTED^^^Yes`;

function stringToObj(str) {
  const branches = str.split('|||');
  const obj = {};
  branches.forEach((branch) => {
    const leaves = branch.split('^^^');
    const [top, sub, answer] = leaves;
    if (top) {
      if (!obj[top]) obj[top] = {};
      const trimmedAnswer = answer.trim();
      const curr = obj[top][sub];
      if (curr) {
        obj[top][sub] = `${curr}, ${trimmedAnswer}`;
      } else {
        obj[top][sub] = answer.trim();
      }
    }
  });

  return obj;
} 

console.log(stringToObj(string));
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas. This is nice and its getting close. But its its missing out on 'sub' having 2 answers. Like in the above FEVER  has 2 answers.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you LMulvey and Lucas. This is terrific and clears up lots of issues

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use the `split` function.
You could do a first split on the string for `"|||"`, after that you could split all the resulting strings for `"^^^"`, so that you can divide keys and values.

Something like that (take it as pseudocode)

```
let strings = data.split("|||");
for (string in strings){
  let objectKeyValue = string.split("^^^");
  let object = objectKeyValue[0];
  let key = objectKeyValue[1];
  let value = objectKeyValue[2];
}
```

from here, compose your object and you're good to go.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split